# How to record voice and send it to server?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I need to record the voice of the student from the client and send it to server to check whether there are any gramatical mistakes in it. I have designed the client in flex.

My problem is, i have no idea of how to store the recorded sound and send it to the server. can you guys give some guidelines? And one more question is red5 better than flash media server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red5 and FMS both can do the recording task for you.

For recording, you have to use the NetStream class. That will send the recording real-time to the server. When closing the NetStream make sure the buffer is empty so you don't cut the recording.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot record the sound on the client.the recording and the sending is a single seamless process.

About the servers, I don't know if better is the correct question, it's free so I'd rather use it in this case.